# Using different internal network mask within a single server

Tags: openvpn

I need to configure openvpn on server with one IP (213.11.23.155, vpn.example.com) for multiple networks, for example:

Network 1 computers:

125.16.1.1

125.16.1.2

Network 2 computers:

125.16.2.1

125.16.2.2

125.16.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you will want to start OpenVPN will multiple configs which reside in /etc/openvpn. Please take note that you'll need to make sure that `port ####` will have to have a different value for each configuration and that you'll be using, as well as those ports opened up on your firewall.

Also, please note that the 125.16/16 subnet is not allocated for personal use. If you use that space in your configuration it will interfere with connectivity to those actual machines. For internal network purposes you'll want to use the subnets listed here:

```
10.0.0.0    10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
172.16.0.0  172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

Simple config modifications would be as follows:

Config 1:

```
port 1194
server 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.0
```

Config 2:

```
port 1195
server 10.20.40.0 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start openvpn with 2 config files (by default it starts all the config files in the /etc/openvpn directory) so you will have 2 vpn and you configure each one with a different subnet.